# How to embed a JavaFX program in a D2L window

Tags: javafx, desire2learn

I have a small program written in JavaFX that I would like to embed in the browser window accessed by students within D2L. I have tested my HTML code and it works fine outside of D2L. When I load the HTML file, the .jnlp file, and the javascript file onto the D2L file system, the HTML displays the text within the window okay, but the region in which the JavaFX program should be embedded/displayed shows the following message:

*JavaFX application could not launch due to system configuration (show error details). See java.com/javafx for troubleshooting information.*

I am probably being rather naive to think that I could embed the java program without some tinkering, but I don't know where to start in trouble shooting the problem. Clicking on the link that is supposed to provide additional details regarding the source of the problem doesn't go anywhere.

**I do not want to access any data from D2L.** I only want to run my Java program within a window in D2L.

The HTML code I am using was generated by NetBeans and then tweaked by me:

```
 <html><head>
  <script src="/content/FS14/PSL/534/FS14-PSL-534-301-97EJCN-EL-46-668/Video  Files/dtjava.js"></script>

<script>
    function javafxEmbed() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : '/content/FS14/PSL/534/FS14-PSL-534-301-97EJCN-EL-46-668/Video Files/StripChartRecorder.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : 1000,
                height : 600,
            params: {
        System: 'Neuron', 
        Scenario: 'Automaticity'
        }
        },
        {
            javafx : '7.0+'
        },
        {}
    );
}

<!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2><b>Automaticity in Neurons</b></h2>

<hr />
<p><br /> <!-- Applet will be inserted here --></p>
<div id="javafx-app-placeholder"></div>
<p></p>
<hr />
<p><br /> <b>Questions &amp; Problem solving</b></p>
<hr />
</body></html>
```

Comment: Hi Bill, where in the D2L system are you trying to embed the HTML file? e.g. content topic, homepage widget, etc

Comment: I have uploaded the HTML as a content topic (file) within a module. When a student clicks on the HTML file/topic name, the module window expands and the text encoded by the HTML is displayed. I want the Java simulator to be embedded in this display of text.

Comment: Clarification: When I referred to a Java simulator in my previous comment I was referring to a Java program that generates a graphical simulation of a physiological process.